# should I destroy directive scope or angular will do it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could you please explain me one thing. Imagine we have directive called "myDirective". Here is html:

```
<div my-directive>
</div>
```

When we remove this div from DOM, will angular destroy scope of myDirective and its watchers or I have to listen the event "$destroy" on div DOM element and inside the listener to call scope.$destroy?

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you remove a div from DOM, angularJS automatically deallocates events and destroys the scope, even if you don't listen to $destroy event.
So why you should use $destroy? You should use it to manually deallocate some non angularJS events and plugins (e.g. if you create a 'Kendo Grid' inside myDirective you need to destroy it inside the $destroy function using the plugin function to destroy it).
I suggest also to set all references to objects in the scope to null (best practice).

Comment: In my project I have some directive. When I remove DOM element which this directive was attached to, the watchers from scope of this directive are not removed, so I have to do this for watchers to be removed:

element.on('$destroy', function() {
 scope.$destroy();
});